# Trouble using PrimeNG components (No directive annotation found)

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

I am having trouble using the PrimeNG components (beta5) with angular2 (rc.1). When trying to use any component, e.g. the menubar, I always get the error

> No Directive annotation found on Menubar

I have just started learning angular and PrimeNG so I am probably doing something wrong. But after much googling I could not find any help.

What is the reason that there seem to be no annotations on the
Menubar component? What am I doing wrong?

Note that I am trying to use plain javascript, i.e. not TypeScript. (Well, in fact, I am using Python [via Brython], but that is another matter entirely.)

My index.html starts like this:

```
<script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>

<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>

<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.umd.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/@angular/core/core.umd.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/@angular/common/common.umd.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/@angular/compiler/compiler.umd.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/platform-browser.umd.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js"></script>

<!-- SystemJS -->
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="app/systemjs.config.js"></script>

<!-- PRIME NG-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/primeui/themes/omega/theme.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/font-awesome-4.6.2/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/primeui/primeui-ng-all.min.css" />

 <script src='app/main.js'></script>
```

My `app/main.js` is simple:

```
(function(app) {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    System.import("primeng/primeng").then(function(primeng) {
        app.AppComponent =
            ng.core.Component({
                selector: 'my-app',
                template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>',
                directives: [primeng.Menubar]
            })
            .Class({
                constructor: function() {}
            });
        ng.platformBrowserDynamic.bootstrap(app.AppComponent);
    });
  });
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

The `app/system.config.js` script contains:

```
(function(global) {

   // map tells the System loader where to look for things
var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'primeng':                    'node_modules/primeng'
};

// packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
var packages = {
//         'app':                        { main: 'boot.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'primeng':                    { defaultExtension: 'js' }
};

var packageNames = [
    '@angular/common',
    '@angular/compiler',
    '@angular/core',
    '@angular/http',
    '@angular/platform-browser',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
    '@angular/router',
    '@angular/router-deprecated',
    '@angular/testing',
    '@angular/upgrade',
];

// add package entries for angular packages in the form '@angular/common': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
packageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
    packages[pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
});

var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
}

// filterSystemConfig - index.html's chance to modify config before we register it.
if (global.filterSystemConfig) { global.filterSystemConfig(config); }

System.config(config);

})(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the installation of PrimeNG. This is a beta version which enables you to use components in Angular2. It is similar to PrimeUI.

For installation instructions check this link http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup

There is a quickstart and a good explanation on how to get it up and running. Unfortunately the `AppComponent` is written in `TypeScript`, but it should give you great pointers as to how to continue.

Besides that, it is not necessary to add the `@angular` js files inside your `index.html`. They get loaded through `SystemJS`

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I went through that (actually through the version at github, since currently the link still contains instructions for Beta 4 which doesn't (?) work with angular2 rc.1) and got to the point which I described in my question. Unfortunately I haven't been able to get any further.

Comment: @jonathanverner but the instructions are written for `angular2.0.0-rc.1`. They updated to beta 5 :). Check here [http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=3918](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=3918)

Comment: Did you really read them?? They are for the old version, they haven't been updated yet (at the time of writing this comment, anyway). Anyway, the problem is not with the version of the instructions (I've been able to find the updated instructions at github) but that I haven't been able to make them work...

Comment: Yes I've read it? The `package.json` in their instructions speak of `"primeng": "1.0.0-beta.5"` and about the angular2.0.0-rc1 version. Perhaps clear your browser cache?